# Does Shopify have a default email marketing campaign?

Tags: email, shopify, mailchimp

I just want to ask if shopify has default email marketing campaign so I can collect, send to, track online cycle, cart abandonment, etc?

Does shopify have its own platform for doing so? or the only way is to add third party app like mailchimp?

Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shopify has emails for everything transactional which you can view under Settings -> Notifications, as well as abandoned cart emails.

They don't offer a marketing email platform, you would have to use something like Mailchimp, Klayvio, Campaign Monitor etc. Shopify allows you to use these for transactional (except the initial order confirmation email) and abandoned cart emails as well if you'd like to customize them more.